# Cassandra Apache query

Tags: cassandra

I have a problems with a table in cassandra. Below is what I did:

`CREATE KEYSPACE tfm WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };`

I'm working in one machine.

`CREATE TABLE tfm.foehis(hocpny text, hocol text,honumr text,holinh text,hodtto text,hotour text,hoclic text, hooe  text,hotpac text,hodtac text,hohrac text,hodesf text,hocdan text,hocdrs text,hocdsl text, hoobs text,hotdsc text,honrac text,holinr text,housca text,hodtea text,hohrea text,housea text,hodtcl text,hohrcl text,houscl text,hodtrc text,hohrrc text,housrc text,hodtra text,hohrra text,housra text,hodtcm text,hohrcm text,houscm text,hodtua text,hohrua text,houser text, PRIMARY KEY((hooe,hodtac,hohrac),hoclic));`

Until this point everything is OK. But when I try to do some select queries, I get warnings and errors:

`cqlsh> select count(*) from tfm.foehis;`

`count`

`-------`

`56980`

`(1 rows)`

`Warnings :`
`Aggregation query used without partition key`

`Read 100 live rows and 1055 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM tfm.foehis LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)`

`Read 100 live rows and 1066 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM tfm.foehis WHERE token(hooe, hodtac, hohrac) >= token(1045161613, 20180502, 2304) LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)`

#### And

`cqlsh> select count(*) from tfm.foehis where hoclic=1011;`

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (1011) for "hoclic" of type text"`

`cqlsh>  select count(*) from tfm.foehis where hotpac=ANOE;`

`SyntaxException: line 1:49 no viable alternative at input ';' (...from tfm.foehis where hotpac=[ANOE];)`

I supposed that the problems is in the definition of table, but I don't know where the problems is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your issue is in the queries. Since all your columns are text you need to use simple quotes around values.

Also, according to your table definition, the partition key is formed  by hooe,hodtac,hohrac columns which means that all your queries must include this columns with exact values (=). hoclic will be the clustering column and on this one you will be able to use other operators and ordering.

Also, have in mind that running queries without the partition key is not recommended in Cassandra (like your select) since this will trigger a full cluster scan and you can run in all sorts of problems (for instance, garbage collection issues).

I would recommend some basic reading: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key and https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. When executing the query `select count(*) from tfm.foehis;`, Cassandra will try to look up all the partitions to calculate the count. Cassandra works best when the queries made are pointed, hence the warning.
2. You have defined the column `hoclic` as text and are trying to search using an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid select queries where full table scan is required. As performance will be impacted as cassandra need to make scan on all the partitions.

1) `select count(*) from tfm.foehis where hoclic=1011;` here the value provided is wrong as hoclic is text type . below is the correction :

```
  select count(*) from tfm.foehis where hoclic='1011';
```

2) `select count(*) from tfm.foehis where hotpac=ANOE` I don't see hotpac as part of primary key. Cassandra is required to provide the partition key in search based on parameters.